# Unable to call JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var chart = {
  generateChartData: function() {
     return "hello"
  },
  chartData: generateChartData()
}
```

The above throws an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: generateChartData is not defined`.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems.

1. You've done nothing to create a variable called `generateChartData` in any scope.
2. After the object has finished being constructed, you will have created  `chart.generateChartData` … but that won't exist at the time you are trying to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for `chartData` property and inside you can invoke `generateChartData()` method and get its value.

```js
var chart = {
  generateChartData: function() {
    return "hello"
  },
  get chartData() {
    return this.generateChartData()
  }
}

console.log(chart.chartData)
```